# TinyXML2 get text from node and all subnodes

Tags: c++, tinyxml2

How does one go about getting the text from the nodes and subnodes in TinyXML2?

The XMLPrinter class seems to do what I need, but it does not print the text properly.

My XML:

```
<div>The quick brown <b>fox</b> jumps over the <i>lazy</i> dog.</div>
```

My class which extends the XMLPrinter class:

```
class XMLTextPrinter : public XMLPrinter {
    virtual bool    VisitEnter (const XMLDocument &) { return true; }
    virtual bool    VisitExit (const XMLDocument &)  { return true; }
    virtual bool    VisitEnter (const XMLElement &e, const XMLAttribute *)  {
        auto text = e.GetText();
        if(text) {
            std::cout << text;
        }
        return true;
    }
    virtual bool    VisitExit (const XMLElement &e)  { return true; }
    virtual bool    Visit (const XMLDeclaration &)  { return true; }
    virtual bool    Visit (const XMLText &e) { return true; }
    virtual bool    Visit (const XMLComment &)  { return true; }
    virtual bool    Visit (const XMLUnknown &)  { return true; }
};
```

My code:

```
XMLDocument document;
document.Parse(..., ...);

auto elem = ...;

XMLTextPrinter printer;
elem->Accept(&printer);
```

The output:

```
The quick brown foxlazy
```

Why is it ignoring all text which come after the `<b>` and `<i>` elements? How can I solve this? Also, the XMLPrinter class properly prints it out *with* the tags, but I do not want the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edited 14-Apr-17 to improve (I hope).]

`XMLPrinter` derives from `XMLVisitor` and prints the XML document (or element) in full, tags, attributes and all. `XMLVisitor` does the work of recursing up and down the XML hierarchy, calling default, do nothing, implementations of methods `VisitEnter`/`VisitExit` for nodes that can have descendants (children), i.e. documents and elements and ``Visit` for leaf nodes, i.e. text, comments etc. Override these methods in a derived class to implement the desired functionality.

The first problem is that you are modifying `XMLPrinter`. This derives from `XMLVisitor` and creates a printable representation of the XML document. But then you replace all `XMLPrinter`'s *visit...* methods with your own. It would be much better, and less work, to derive from `XMLVisitor` directly.

Secondly, you're getting the element text from `VisitEnter` alone using `GetText()` which will not work when child nodes are embedded in it [as documented here](http://grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2docs/classtinyxml2_1_1_x_m_l_element.html#accc366b0e6bb41ee59b204726959d864).

In this case, to get only the text of all elements override `Visit` for the text leaf nodes, i.e. `Visit(const XMLText &)`.

```
#include "tinyxml2.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace tinyxml2;

class XMLPrintText : public XMLVisitor
{
public:
   virtual bool Visit (const XMLText & txt) override
   {
      std::cout << txt .Value();
      return true;
   }
};

int main()
{
   XMLDocument doc;
   doc.Parse ("<div>The quick brown <b>fox</b> jumps over the <i>lazy</i> dog.</div>");
   auto div = doc .FirstChildElement();
   XMLPrintText prt;
   div -> Accept (&prt);
   return 0;
}
```